# Printing the content of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, printing

How do I print the content of a specific div with Javascript or Jquery? I know you can use `window.print();` but that prints the whole page.

Also the div that I wish to print has a vertical scroll, if that needs to be mentioned.

Comment: Use a print stylesheet

Comment: Specify @media rules in your CSS to control what is shown/hidden (and any other css directives) in each of various media devices, chiefly "all", "print" and "screen" but also several others - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@media).

Comment: Or try changing your design to use an iframe and try `iframe.print()`

Answer (score -1):

I use this to do the job you are asking: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm